# Only one mapper when backing up DynamoDB to S3 using EMR and Hive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I have a DynamoDB table in production with about 1.5 billion objects.  I am writing an EMR script to back up the table to S3.  I would prefer it to be done as quickly as possible.  I have a script that provisions an EMR cluster with 4 m4.2xlarge nodes and runs the following hive queries:

```
SET dynamodb.throughput.read.percent = 1.5;
SET dynamodb.throughput.write.percent = 1.5;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET io.seqfile.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec = org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db;
USE my_db;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ddb_table (composite_key string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "my_ddb_table", "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "composite_key:composite_key");

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://s3-backups/ddb/' SELECT composite_key FROM ddb_table;
```

When I run the script with on demand RCU's the job spawns 62 tasks.  When I run the script with provisioned RCU's, I get only one task (about 800 RCU's consumed per minute).  Neither the amount of provisioned RCU's (I tested with 40,000 RCUs) nor autoscaling seems to change the number of tasks.  Only on-demand RCU's seems to create additional tasks.

Other than AWS wanting me to pay more money, is there a reason for this behavior or a workaround?  Provisioning more capacity and having less utilization of that provisioned capacity seems counter-intuitive.

For now I start my job with on demand RCU's and then switch to provisioned after the job starts...but that is not very fun.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly this issue only seems to occur when reading data from my dynamo table, not writing to my dynamo table.

Comment: I was seeing this issue reading and writing to DDB

Answer (score 1):

The new EMR versions seem to require dynamodb.throughput.write/read parameters that you need to manually specify(which wasn't the case in older versions). E.g.

```
SET dynamodb.throughput.write=40000        // depending on your RCU
SET dynamodb.throughput.write.percent=0.9 
SET dynamodb.throughput.read=40000         // depending on your WCU
SET dynamodb.throughput.read.percent=0.9
```

Comment: Two days working with AWS Support and they didn't find this solution...